# If God is no respecter of persons, how to explain Exodus 11:7?

Tags: exodus

> Exodus 11:7
> But among the Israelites not a dog will bark at any person or animal. Then you will know that the LORD makes a distinction between Egypt and Israel.

I often hear on Christian radio stations: God is no respecter of persons.

How does one believe that and Exodus 11:7?

Answer (score 9):

When it is written that “God is not a respecter of persons,”<sup>1</sup> it means that salvation is for all who believe, whether Jew or Gentile,<sup>2</sup> hence Jude refers to it as “the common salvation.”<sup>3</sup>

However, the context of Exo. 11 is the final plague that Yavheh would inflict upon Egypt. Yahveh would make a distinction between Israel and Egypt by personally protecting Israel while the destroyer<sup>4</sup> passed through Egypt and killed all the Egyptian firstborn.

Acts 10:34 is referring to impartiality with respect to salvation, while Exo. 11:7 is referring to partiality or distinction with respect to a plague.

```
Footnotes
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> Acts 10:34</sup>
        <sup><sup>2</sup> Acts 10:35 cf. Rom. 1:16</sup>
        <sup><sup>3</sup> Jude 1:3: «τῆς κοινῆς σωτηρίας»</sup>
        <sup><sup>4</sup> Exo. 12:23</sup>

Comment: The other dimension. An important one! I answered this earlier, but you’ve completed it. +1

Answer (score 2):

Your question relates to ‘man’, but the evidence you provided to support refers to nations.
And God does respect HIS nation. For any other nation to participate in his goodness, you must also respect his nation.

GEN 12:2 *And I will make of thee a great nation, and I will bless thee, and make thy name great; and thou shalt be a blessing:*

He is God of only one nation. BUT he is God of all people. And in this he is not a respecter of persons.

Answer (score 1):

- YHVH desires devoted individuals to join His chosen people. - In [Devarim (Deuteronomy) 1:36], Khalev (Caleb) not Moshe (Moses) got to see the Promised land - because he (Khalev, כָּלֵ֤ב ) completely followed YHVH. (יַ֕עַן אֲשֶׁ֥ר מִלֵּ֖א אַֽחֲרֵ֥י יְהֹוָֽה)

In [Shemot (Exodus) 9:1] YHVH calls Himself "God of the Hebrews" (אֱלֹהֵ֣י הָֽעִבְרִ֔ים) , Eloi Ha-Ivrim.

- In [Shemot (Exodus) 4:22] YHVH said My first-born Son is Yisrael : " אָמַ֣ר יְהֹוָ֔ה בְּנִ֥י בְכֹרִ֖י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל ".

In [Yehoshua (Joshua) 10:40] "YHVH, my God of Yisrael" (יְהֹוָ֖ה אֱלֹהֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל)

- In [Yehoshua (Joshua) 10:44] because "YHVH, my God of Yisrael, fought for Yisrael" (יְהֹוָה֙ אֱלֹהֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל נִלְחָ֖ם לְיִשְׂרָאֵֽל)

In [Hoshea (Hosea) 11:1] "For, when Yisrael was young, I loved him, and from Egypt I called My Son." ( כִּ֛י נַ֥עַר יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל וָאֹֽהֲבֵ֑הוּ וּמִמִּצְרַ֖יִם קָרָ֥אתִי לִבְנִֽי )